# How to get active column Name from one sheet to other in Excel 2013

Tags: excel

I have two sheet in an excel document. The first sheet contains columns named Stage1, Stage2, Stage3, Stage4 and below each stage contains the date and percentage of completion (two separate columns). The second sheet contains a column for Active Stage and date of the stage. I want to fill the active stage and date based on first sheet by the data entered i.e if there is any data at stage 1 then it will be the active stage, if there is any data at stage 2 then it will be the active stage and so on and corresponding date for each stage. How can I get this?

[image: Screenshot of First Sheet]

Comment: What did you try? You could start reading [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/if-cell-contains) instruction page.

Comment: It would help to show a screenshot of your first sheet.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I am trying to use IF(ISBlank('Sheet1'$A$2, "blank", "A2") but how will I use it for all columns for stages.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have updated my question to include the screenshot

Comment: What have you tried? There may be a way to do this with `MAX` and `INDEX/MATCH`? Can you post a sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below formula

```
="Search" & INT(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A3:$M3),0),0)/2)
```